# Make Unioned Queries show on the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of queries that go by each month. They hit against a set of account numbers, but when they return they show a staggered result:

```
554000  355 Transportation  COS-Fuel    NULL                    68652.230000000000
554000  355 Transportation  COS-Fuel    48923.270000000000  NULL
```

I would like them to be joined together (that's only two months, it'll get messy with ass 12)

```
554000  355 Transportation  COS-Fuel  48923.270000000000   68652.230000000000
```

Here's how i have it set up:

```
    ---JAN Actuals
set @month = '1'
 SET @1Start = (SELECT StartDate FROM MiscReportTables.dbo.FiscalCalendar WHERE @year = [Year] AND Period = 1)
 SET @1End = (SELECT EndDate FROM MiscReportTables.dbo.FiscalCalendar WHERE @year = [Year] AND Period = 1)
Select distinct 
    LEDGERTRANS.Dimension as 'Department', 
    DIMENSIONS.DESCRIPTION as 'Division', 
    LedgerTable.AccountName as 'GL Description',
Case When @month = '1' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST) END as '1',
Case When @month = '2' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '2',
Case When @month = '3' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '3',
Case When @month = '4' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST) END  as '4',
Case When @month = '5' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '5',
Case When @month = '6' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST) END  as '6',
Case When @month = '7' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST) END  as '7',
Case When @month = '8' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '8',
Case When @month = '9' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '9',
Case When @month = '10' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '10',
Case When @month = '11' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '11',
Case When @month = '12' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '12'
Into #tempJan
from LEDGERTRANS 
Join LedgerTable on LedgerTable.Accountnum = Ledgertrans.AccountNum
Join Dimensions on NUM = LEDGERTRANS.Dimension2_
where transdate BETWEEN @1Start AND @1End and LedgerTrans.Dimension2_ in (@division)
Group By LEDGERTRANS.AccountNum,LEDGERTRANS.Dimension,LEDGERTRANS.Dimension2_,LedgerTable.AccountName,DIMENSIONS.DESCRIPTION

---FEB Actuals
set @month = '2'
 SET @2Start = (SELECT StartDate FROM MiscReportTables.dbo.FiscalCalendar WHERE @year = [Year] AND Period = dbo.fnGetPeriod(2,@month))
 SET @2End = (SELECT EndDate FROM MiscReportTables.dbo.FiscalCalendar WHERE @year = [Year] AND Period = dbo.fnGetPeriod(2,@month))
Select distinct 
    LEDGERTRANS.Dimension as 'Department', 
    DIMENSIONS.DESCRIPTION as 'Division', 
    LedgerTable.AccountName as 'GL Description',
Case When @month = '1' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST) END as '1',
Case When @month = '2' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '2',
Case When @month = '3' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '3',
Case When @month = '4' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST) END  as '4',
Case When @month = '5' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '5',
Case When @month = '6' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST) END  as '6',
Case When @month = '7' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST) END  as '7',
Case When @month = '8' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '8',
Case When @month = '9' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '9',
Case When @month = '10' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '10',
Case When @month = '11' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '11',
Case When @month = '12' Then SUM(AMOUNTMST)  END as '12'
Into #tempFeb
from LEDGERTRANS 
Join LedgerTable on LedgerTable.Accountnum = Ledgertrans.AccountNum
Join Dimensions on NUM = LEDGERTRANS.Dimension2_
where transdate BETWEEN @2Start AND @2End and LedgerTrans.Dimension2_ in (@division)
Group By LEDGERTRANS.AccountNum,LEDGERTRANS.Dimension,LEDGERTRANS.Dimension2_,LedgerTable.AccountName,DIMENSIONS.DESCRIPTION


SELECT distinct LedgerTable.AccountNum,
    Department, 
    Division, 
    [GL Description], 
    [1],
    [2]
from #tempFeb join LedgerTable on LedgerTable.AccountName = #tempFeb.[GL Description]

union
SELECT distinct LedgerTable.AccountNum,
    Department, 
    Division, 
    [GL Description], 
    [1],
    [2]
from #tempJan join LedgerTable on LedgerTable.AccountName = #tempJan.[GL Description]

drop table #tempJan
drop table #tempFeb
```

Comment: That is what a `UNION` does, it basically stacks result sets.  If you want it in a single row, then you need to use a join.

Comment: How would a join work in this situation? i'm kind of blustering my way through all this

Comment: Threw some psuedo code together below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other option maybe is aggregate:

```
SELECT
    T.AccountNum,
    T.Department,
    T.Division,
    SUM(ISNULL(T.JAN, 0)) AS JAN,
    SUM(ISNULL(T.FEB, 0)) AS FEB
FROM (
    SELECT distinct 
        LedgerTable.AccountNum,
        Department, 
        Division, 
        [GL Description], 
        [1] AS JAN,
        [2] AS FEB
    FROM 
        #tempFeb
    JOIN LedgerTable 
        ON LedgerTable.AccountName = #tempFeb.[GL Description]

    UNION

    SELECT distinct 
        LedgerTable.AccountNum,
        Department, 
        Division, 
        [GL Description], 
        [1] AS JAN,
        [2] AS FEB
    FROM 
        #tempJan 
    JOIN LedgerTable 
        ON LedgerTable.AccountName = #tempJan.[GL Description]
) T
GROUP BY
    T.AccountNum,
    T.Department,
    T.Division
```

Comment: i keep getting a Invalid column name 'JAN'.

Comment: You shouldn't if you query exactly this way.
But I suggest you to name your columns as something else instead of '1', '2'....

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a join instead of a union.
Something like:

```
select
t1.department,
t1.division,
t1.[GL Description],
t1.1,
t2.1
...
from

(
SELECT distinct LedgerTable.AccountNum,
    Department, 
    Division, 
    [GL Description], 
    [1],
    [2]
from #tempFeb join LedgerTable on LedgerTable.AccountName = #tempFeb.[GL Description]
) t1
inner join
(
SELECT distinct LedgerTable.AccountNum,
    Department, 
    Division, 
    [GL Description], 
    [1],
    [2]
from #tempJan join LedgerTable on LedgerTable.AccountName = #tempJan.[GL Description]
) t2
on t1.departement = t2.department
and t1.division = t2.division
and t1.[GL Description] = t2.[GL Description]
```

That's not exact code, in particular I don't understand your aliases (your columns named 1,2).

Comment: The alias is 1 for January 2 for February, etc

Comment: That provides me with all the stuff on the same line, but with the stuff for each query separated next to one another

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell from the code you posted where you are getting the last 2 columns in each result set from.

Comment: Do you want to add all the values in [1] together, etc?

Comment: [1] is already together. it will only be hit once or it will be null
Lets call [1] January and [2] february (which i should do). I want it to be:
Account num|Department|Description|January total|February total

Comment: You've got 12 sums in each temp table, for Jan - Dec. Are you trying to add up those 12 for each temp table?

Comment: nope. Just want to show the totals that were gathered in the temp tables. side by side. this report will show a whole years worth of totals by month, but no sum at the end

Comment: Andrew, your method of joining the tables works fine. Just a little long since I have so many months ;)

Comment: What do you do with the joins when one of the months temp tables is null. For instance, there is no data for April, so now the join returns nothing and everything is blank